# Photon trapping curve version 2

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283732/64809), I ask about the existence of a smooth curve that traps light in a certain direction in a confined domain. I get a nice [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3284448/64809). Here is an extension of that question.

Is there a closed smooth planar curve and a nonzero length interval of angles satisfying the following property?

The closed smooth curve separates the plane into two disconnected domains, one interior the other exterior. Cut a finite connected segment, called opening, out of the curve. "Shoot" a "photon" through the opening into the interior along a direction in the aforementioned angle interval. The photon bounces off of the curve with the same angle as the incident line with respect to the normal vector of the curve. The photon will remain trapped inside the interior after traversing an infinitely long distance.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read "Geometry and Billiards" by Serge Tabachnikov: http://descartes.math.psu.edu/tabachni/Books/billiardsgeometry.pdf

Comment: @Aretino: Thank you for introducing to this gem of a paper. The higher directory has other nuggets of gold as well.